# Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /app/resources/views/products/productView.blade.php)

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, heroku, heroku-postgres

can anyone help me with this error? my project is working fine on local server but when I push to heroku it gives me the below error. Any help ?

I am using `php version 7.3.7` and `laravel version 6.18.3` also I am using heroku for the first time.
I have uploaded the code

```
**Product View**
@foreach($products as $p)
<section class="section single-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sx-12 text-center">

                    <h3>{{$p->product_name}}</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content-top">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6">

                </div> 

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cen-xs text-right">
                    <div class="bread">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                          <li class="active">{{$p->product_name}}</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->
        </div><!-- end content top -->

        <div class="row">
            <div id="singlewrapper" class="col-md-8">
                <div class="content nopad">
                    <div class="item-single-wrapper">
                        <div class="item-box">
                            <div class="item-media text-center">
                                <div id="slider" class="flexslider clearfix">

                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/'.array_first(json_decode($p->filename))) }}" style="width:700px; height:400px;" alt="" class="img-responsive"></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider clearfix">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li>
                                            @foreach (json_decode($p->filename) as $picture)
                                                <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/'.$picture) }}" style="height:120px; width:200px"/>       
                                            @endforeach
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                            </div><!-- end item-media -->

                            <div class="item-desc">
                                <b>Description</b>
                                <p> {{$p->description}} </p>
                            </div><!-- end item-desc -->

                            <center>
                                <p>__________</p>
                            </center>

                            @if(count($comments)>0)
                                <div class="item-desc">
                                <b>Comments</b>
                                    @foreach($comments as $c)
                                        <p> {{$c->comments}} </p>
                                        {{$c->users['username']}}
                                        <h6> by <b>{{$c->user['username']}}</b> at <b>{{$c->created_at}}</b> </h6>  <br/>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div><!-- end item-desc -->
                            @else 
                                <div class="item-desc">
                                <b>Comments</b>
                                <p> No comments found </p>
                                </div><!-- end item-desc -->
                            @endif

                        </div><!-- end item-box -->


                    </div><!-- end item-single-wrapper -->
                </div><!-- end content -->
            </div><!-- end singlewrapper -->

            <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
                <div class="boxes boxs">
                    <div class="item-price text-center">
                        <p>${{$p->price}}</p>
                        <em><a href="#">Regular License</a></em>
                        <!-- <div class="rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        </div> -->
                        <hr>
                        <small> 
                        @if((Auth::check()) && ($findLikes == true))
                            <a href="/unlike-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="0" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> UnLike</a> </small>
                        @else
                            <a href="/liked-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="1" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like it</a> </small>
                        @endif
                        <hr>
                        <a href="/add-to-cart/{{$p->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>

                        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Comment</button></a>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add your comments here <span class="fa fa-comment"></span></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="login-form">
                                        <form method="post" action="/product-comment/{{$p->id}}">

                                        @csrf
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" name="comment" required class="form-control" placeholder="comment here" />
                                            </div>

                                            <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div><!-- end login-form -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href=""></a>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Add Comment</button>
                             </div> -->
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <ul class="list-inline social">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end price -->
                </div><!-- end boxes -->

                <div class="boxes boxs">
                    <div class="desiger-details text-center">
                        <img src="upload/member_05.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                        <h4><a href="public-profile.html">{{$p->username}}</a></h4>
                        <small><a href="/follow-user/{{$p->user_id}}"><i class="fa fa-user-plus">
                        @if((Auth::check()) && ($findFollow == true))
                            </i> Unfollow</a> </small>
                        @else
                            </i> Follow {{$p->username}}</a> </small>
                        @endif
                    </div><!-- end designer -->
                </div><!-- end boxes -->

                <div class="boxes boxs">
                    <div class="item-details">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Created on:</td>
                                <td>{{$p->created_at}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Category</td>
                                <td>{{optional($p->category)->category_name}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Followers:</td>
                                <td>{{$p->user->followers}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Likes:</td>
                                <td>{{$p->total_likes}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Comments:</td>
                                <td>{{$p->total_comments}}</td>
                            </tr>


                        </table>
                    </div><!-- end item-details -->
                </div><!-- end boxes -->
            </div><!-- end sidebar -->
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</section>

@endforeach

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <div class="media cen-xs">
                    <p>
                        &copy; Catalog INC. 2016 - All Rights Reserverd.<br>
                        Idea by <a class="madeby" href="http://showwp.com">Show WP</a> made with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> coded with <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                <ul class="list-inline text-right cen-xs">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Site Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Copyrights</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">License</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
                    <li><a class="topbutton" href="#">Back to top <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</footer><!-- end footer -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
<!-- END SITE -->

<script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<!-- FlexSlider JavaScript
================================================== -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/flexslider.js')}}"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
"use strict";
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        itemWidth: 92,
        itemMargin: 0,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel"
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>


</body>
</html>`
```

**Product Controller**

```
public function showProductDescription($id) {

// echo $id;

$category = Category::all()->sortBy('category_name');
// $category->category_name;
$userLikes = new Comment();

$products = Product::where('id', $id)->get();
$comments = Comment::where('product_id', $id)->get();

$commentCount = Comment::where('product_id', $id)->get('comments')->count(); 
$pag = Comment::where('product_id', $id)->paginate(10);

if(Auth::check()) {
    $carts = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('active', '=', '1')->count();

    $findFollow = Following::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('followed_to', $id)->first();

    $findLikes = Comment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('product_id', $id)->first();


                    // dd(Product::all());
                    // dd($findFollow);
                    // dd($findLikes);
                    // dd($pag);
                    // dd($commentCount);
                    // die();

    return view('products.productView', compact('products', 'comments', 'pag', 'commentCount', 'carts', 'findFollow', 'category', 
                    'userLikes', 'findLikes'));

} else {
    $carts = Cart::where('active', '=', '1')->count();

    $findFollow = '';

    $findLikes = '';

                    // dd(Product::all());
                    // dd($findFollow);
                    // dd($findLikes);
                    // dd($pag);
                    // dd($commentCount);
                    // die();

    return view('products.productView', compact('products', 'comments', 'pag', 'commentCount', 'carts', 'findFollow', 'category', 
                                            'userLikes', 'findLikes'));
}


}

public function likedProduct($id) {

if(Auth::check()) {

    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();

    $userLikes = new Comment();
    $userLikes->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userLikes->product_id = $product->id;
    $userLikes->likes = '1';

    $userLikes->save();

    if($product->total_likes == 0) {
        $product->total_likes = 1;
    } else {
        $product->total_likes = $product->total_likes + 1;
    }

    $product->save();
    return redirect()->action('ProductController@showProductDescription', ['id' => $id]);
} else {
    Session::flash("message", "OOPS! You dont have permission to upload the items. Please register first.");
    return redirect("/register-user");
}
}

public function unlikeProduct($id) {

if(Auth::check()) {
    $comments = Comment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                            ->where('product_id', $id)->delete();


    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->get('total_likes')->count();

    // echo $product;
    // die();

    if($product>0) {
        $productLikes = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
        $productLikes->total_likes = $productLikes->total_likes - 1;
        $productLikes->save();
    }

    // Session::flash("message", "OOPS! You dont have permission to upload the items. Please register first.");
    return redirect()->action('ProductController@showProductDescription', ['id' => $id]);
} else {
    Session::flash("message", "OOPS! You dont have permission to upload the items. Please register first.");
    return redirect("/register-user");
}


}
public function productComment($id) {
if(Auth::check()) {

    $c = Input::get('comment');

    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();

    $user_comments = new Comment();
    $user_comments->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user_comments->product_id = $product->id;
    $user_comments->comments = $c;

    $user_comments->save();

    if($product->total_comments == 0) {
        $product->total_comments = 1;
    } else {
        $product->total_comments = $product->total_comments + 1;
    }

    $product->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Your comment has been added successfully');
    return redirect()->action('ProductController@showProductDescription', ['id' => $id]);


}  else {
    Session::flash("message", "OOPS! You dont have permission to upload the items. Please register first.");
    return redirect("/register-user");
}     
}
```

I have updated the code so if you can help identifying the problem as I failed to identify the problem for the last one and half day and I need to get this fixed

Comment: View errors are very hard to debug, i believe this could be your culprit $c->user can you remove all usages of this and see if it helps?

Comment: I just got it fixed. Thank you :)

Comment: Did that help or else please post your answer.

Comment: else post were helpful

Comment: can you help me with this ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956460/trying-to-get-property-likes-of-non-object-view-app-resources-views-product