# Trying to get property 'likes' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/products/productView.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

on my local server this is working and on hosting (when I push it on heroku) it gives me an error. I dont know where I am doing this wrong

`Trying to get property 'likes' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/products/productView.blade.php)`

Query

`$findLikes = Comment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('product_id', $id)->first();`

View

```
@if((Auth::check()) && ($findLikes->likes == '1'))

    <a href="/unlike-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="0" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> UnLike</a> </small>

@elseif((Auth::check()) && ($findLikes->likes == '0'))

    <a href="/liked-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="1" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like it</a> </small>

@endif
```

THIS IS I WHAT TRIED NOW AND NOT RETURNING ANYTHING BUT LOADING THE PAGE

```
@if((Auth::check()) && $findLikes)
    @if($findLikes->likes == '1')
       <a href="/unlike-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="0" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> UnLike</a> </small>
    @else
       <a href="/liked-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="1" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like it</a> </small>
     @endif
@endif
```

***UPDATED***

Comment: Make sure `$findLikes` is not null before you try to use it. Most likely it didn't find any results.

Comment: I did this and its not display anything

`@if((Auth::check()) && $findLikes)`
`@if($findLikes->likes == '1')`
`<a href="/unlike-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="0" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> UnLike</a> </small>`
 `@else`
`<a href="/liked-product/{{$p->id}}" id="myNumber" name="likes" value="1" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like it</a> </small>`
                                    `@endif`
                                `@endif`

Comment: Then it sounds like there are no matching likes. You can verify results by using `php artisan tinker` on the command line, and try running the query with the user ID and product ID you're attempting.

Comment: its working on my local server but not heroku when I push it

Comment: Did you make sure the data in your database also got uploaded?

Comment: I am using `heroku` and it does not show the database it just allows to configure database but where it is we dont know but we can see the `tables` and `column names`